# Trying to integrate Spring Boot and SWAGGER but getting the "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: "

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to integrate Swagger in spring boot

- My config

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

- my Swagger config class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
//import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket taskApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("task-api")
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/homepage*"))
            .build();
    }


//
//  @Bean
//    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
//        return new UiConfiguration(null);
//    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Simple task API")
                .description("API for managing user tasks")
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**and i'm getting this error no matter what version of swagger i'm using !!**

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader'

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> [2m2023-09-21T13:26:45.334-05:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m
> [35m26607[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m
> [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
> Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/Users/monkeydluffy/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.0.1/springfox-spring-web-2.0.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/Users/monkeydluffy/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.0.1/springfox-spring-web-2.0.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins':
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry':
> FactoryBean threw exception on object creation    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]    at
> com.example.FullstackApplication.main(FullstackApplication.java:10)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/Users/monkeydluffy/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.0.1/springfox-spring-web-2.0.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins':
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry':
> FactoryBean threw exception on object creation    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     ... 24 common frames omitted Caused
> by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins':
> Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry':
> FactoryBean threw exception on object creation    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:716)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     ... 38 common frames omitted Caused
> by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean
> threw exception on object creation    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:90)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1823)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1273)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     ... 53 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/util/comparator/InvertibleComparator  at
> org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry.(OrderAwarePluginRegistry.java:45)
> ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
> org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean.getObject(PluginRegistryFactoryBean.java:36)
> ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
> org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean.getObject(PluginRegistryFactoryBean.java:28)
> ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:148)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]     ... 62 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.util.comparator.InvertibleComparator  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> ~[na:na]  ... 66 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The springfox (documentationProvider): Springfox is deprecated for removal in version 7.0. 0 of openapi-generator. The project seems to be no longer maintained (last commit is of Oct 14, 2020). It works with Spring Boot 2.5. I am seeing that you are using a version greater than 2.5 of spring-boot and I really recommend you to have a switch to another documentation provider like [Spring Doc](https://springdoc.org/)

To do it in a better way just look at [Migration Guide](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html) from springfox to springdoc open api.

Comment: Thanks Lisa for the migration document. Is it that the springdoc-openapi is the new java library thats been widely used for the API documentation in spring-boot now ??

Comment: and u are right i just verified and i'm indeed using  3+ version of spring boot
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
  <relativePath />

Comment: Yes, springdoc-openapi  is using now as a openApi provider

Comment: Also you have to accept this answer for others peoples to know that is the right way to do it when they will meet the same problem I think

Answer (score 0):

definitely one thing to keep an eye out for errors like

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader'

- is the versions of Springfox & your spring boot application and
- incase you don't have any strong need that your project must use
  Springfox , give springdoc-openapi a try for api documentation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).